# Informix Stored procedure with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, informix, ef-database-first

I am new to Informix stuff and I have a legacy database (IBM Informix) and there are thousands of stored procedures written. Now I am trying to create the model class using Entity framework database first approach.

The problem I am facing now is;

When I am trying to add stored procedures from Update Model from Database, noting is list down in the Stored Procedures and Functions. Further I have checked with the server and found that all stored procedures are stored in `sysprocedures` table.

My questions are;

- How can I import these procedures into Entity framework?
- Is it possible to invoke stored procedure without importing?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're using IBM Informix or IBM DB2?  There is no Informix DB2 per se.  Since DB2 has a `sysibm.sysprocedures` table, there is nothing in your question that stops it being pure DB2 except that you mentioned Informix in the text and tags.  Equally, Informix has an `informix.sysprocedures` table so there's nothing in your question that stops it being pure Informix except that you mentioned DB2 in the title and the text and the tags. Given 4 mentions of DB2 and 2 of Informix, I suppose it is more likely a DB2 question than an Informix one, but that's not very safe ground.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am using IBM informix